# gpx file Extension node gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, gpx, garmin

I'm trying to read a GPX file created within a Garmin GPS device. I have the following code to try to pull out all the data, but it hangs up in the  node and it's children, ie.  =>

Here's the code

```
//returns http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1
XNamespace gpx = GetGpxNameSpace();
XDocument gpxDoc = GetGpxDoc();
XNamespace gpxtpx = XNamespace.Get("gpxtpx");
var waypoints = from waypoint in gpxDoc.Descendants(gpx + "trkpt")
                select new
                {
                    Latitude = waypoint.Attribute("lat").Value,
                    Longitude = waypoint.Attribute("lon").Value,
                    Elevation = waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele") != null ?
                        waypoint.Element(gpx + "ele").Value : null,
                    Dt = waypoint.Element(gpx + "time") != null ?
                        waypoint.Element(gpx + "time").Value : null,
                    hr = waypoint.Element(gpx+ "extensions").Element(gpxtpx +"TrackPointExtension").Element(gpxtpx +"hr").Value
                };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var wpt in waypoints)
{
    // This is where we'd instantiate data
    // containers for the information retrieved.
    sb.Append(
        string.Format("Name:{0} Latitude:{1} Longitude:{2} Elevation:{3} Date:{4}\n",
        "x", wpt.Latitude, wpt.Longitude,
        wpt.Elevation, wpt.Dt));
}

return sb.ToString();
```

And the xml node

```
<trkseg>
   <trkpt lon="-111.5252978168428" lat="35.07395471446216">
      <ele>2084.800048828125</ele>
      <time>2012-07-15T14:47:16.000Z</time>
      <extensions>
         <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
            <gpxtpx:hr>155</gpxtpx:hr>
         </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
      </extensions>
   </trkpt>
...
</trkseg>
```

I can access all the other nodes just fine, but when trying to access the hr node, I get errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you get errors it's advised to include them in the question. It will increase the chance you get answer(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
XNamespace gpxtpx = XNamespace.Get("gpxtpx");
```

to

```
XNamespace gpxtpx = XNamespace.Get("http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1");
```

Comment: Gamin managed to make the link obsolete (just as http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v2 and https://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd).

Answer (score 0):

The name space suggestion above works, and I found it necessary to protect against null nodes:

```
HeartRate = trackpoint.Element(gpx + "extensions") != null ?
                                      (trackpoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(gpxtpx + "TrackPointExtension") != null ?
                                       (trackpoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(gpxtpx + "TrackPointExtension").Element(gpxtpx +"hr") != null ? 
                                          trackpoint.Element(gpx + "extensions").Element(gpxtpx + "TrackPointExtension").Element(gpxtpx +"hr").Value : null ) : null   ) : null
```

Comment: On StackOverflow you cannot reference to an answer as "above", because answers with equal score are randomly arranged each time you open the page. So, reference other answers by using answerer's name instead.